# sending POST values javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Don't know why this doesn't work....oh yeah, I'm a newb still. I have a form that posts data to a db, and it works fine if I just use POST. I doesn't work if I pass it to a javascript function with some AJAX and then submit it. It DOES work w/ 'GET' being submitted from the function, does not work with 'POST'. With 'POST' I connect to DB fine, but the values from the form are all blank so the db gets updated w/ a new record that has all it's fields blank. HEre's the fiddle, I put the php code where the CSS is supposed to go: http://jsfiddle.net/DuckofDeath/6var7103/. HEre is a link to the page, all the feedback from the script gets sent tot he page at the top: http://www.modernmediaworld.com/diaboli/register3.php    function checkForm(){

```
     function checkForm(){

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("formFeedback").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;             
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","addNewSeeker.php",true);         
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Comment: You tagged this with jQuery, so if you are using jQuery, why are you not just using `$.ajax` or `$.post`. jQuery handles this low-level ajax stuff for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/6var7103/2/

Comment: you need to pass the query string (the same you would pass with GET) to the `send()` method.

Comment: You do not send up any data to the server. The data from the form is not magically injected into the XMLHttpRequest, you need to put it there.

Comment: Thanx Captain Obvious. I was asking how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it had to be something simple, and after a lot of digging turns out I just had to use FormData:

var f = e.target,
formData = new FormData(f),

Then use it as an argument when you send:

xhr.open("POST", f.action,true);
xhr.send(formData);

this is what my code looks like now:

```
document.getElementById("seekerForm").onsubmit = function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();

var f = e.target,
formData = new FormData(f),
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("formFeedback").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
    $('#formModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
}
                }
xhr.open("POST", f.action,true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are posting data to the server, but you're not sending it anything.   A POST is designed to send globs of info TO a server.   GET is for retrieving a page.   In this situation you are setting the contents of formFeedback with whatever you hear back.   So if that's what you want, stick to GET and switch to jQuery $.Ajax call (since you tagged jQuery ), it makes it much easier.